# How Can I Make Git Ignore Rails Assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Currently Git marks all of my asset pipeline versioned files as Untracked files.  How can I make it ignore all of these versioned files?  I can't just ignore everything in my public/assets dir because I have non asset pipelined files in there as well.  Eventually I should probably move all of these non-versioned files out of that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following entry to your .gitignore file:

```
*[a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9][a-z 0-9].*
```

It will ignore all files that contain a 32 character uuid at the end of their file name.

Comment: Why not just `[a-z0-9]{32}\.` which will catch any hash-like 32 characters long or more followed by a dot?